# Angular 10 | Algolia | Algolia Places: 'container' must point to an <input> element

Tags: angular, typescript, algolia

I am trying to implement algolia the angular way.

I have installed places.js with npm.

Here is the relevant part:

```
@ViewChild("input") private input;
private instance = null;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.input);
    this.instance = places({
      appId: this.dataService.ALGO_APPLICATION_ID,
      apiKey: this.dataService.ALGO_KEY,
      container: this.input,
      type: 'city'
    });
  }
```

It tells me that the container must be an input element, but when I `console.log(this.input)` I see an input element:

[image]

I tried to keep it as short as possible. If more code is required let me know in the comments.

`input` comes from html:

```
<input #input id="algoliaInput" type="search" placeholder="Where are we going?">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`private input` is not an HTMLElement as you can see in the log.

It contains an html element, but it is actually an `ElementRef` object.
So changing your code to the following, works.

```
import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

....

@ViewChild("input") private input: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;
private instance = null;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.input);
    this.instance = places({
      appId: this.dataService.ALGO_APPLICATION_ID,
      apiKey: this.dataService.ALGO_KEY,
      container: this.input.nativeElement, // nativeElement is the real HtmlElement.
      type: 'city'
    });
}
```